# make a request to other site from the rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, request, rake-task

I'm trying to automate my database population with sample objects, so I use rake tasks. I would like to use some data from other website pages. 
I created txt file with url list from where that information supposed to be read and ran into problem: I don't know how to make requests outside from rake task. I need to get response, extract some selectord as RSPEC allows to do. Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For custom rake tasks, you can always create your own plugin. Refer rails guide - [plugins section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html).
In the plugin, you can use get method to get the data from an external URL. Refer ActionDispatch::Integration::RequestHelpers methods for the details.
You can add your own extraction logic and seed the database.

Comment: thank you very much!look forward to try this though it will need some time to make out concreet realization: I'm tooo newbee )))

Comment: generators mentioned in the reference you provided isn't work for Rails 3.1. Is the way of plugin programming changed?